# Can htlatex be used with biblatex these days?

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht, htlatex

The seems to be a never ending story of incompatibilities between htlatex and biblatex. What is the current state of affairs here?

I can't seem to get htlatex to pick up the biblatex citations. It just keeps complaining about `Citation *** on page * undefined on input line **` when I do

```
latex draft1
biber draft1
htlatex draft1
```

Is there a way to get this working or is it just not possible?

Comment: Do you have a bit of code we can experiment with a bit? Does running `htlatex draft1`/`biber draft1`/`htlatex draft1` work? (Just an unsubstantiated guess.)

Comment: I'm frantically working towards a deadline and don't have time to produce a MWE. My hope was that someone knows about the compatibility more generally since this has long been an issue. If someone can say that there are currently no known issues between htlatex and biblatex, then it would make sense for me to start debugging. Your suggested sequence doesn't work either.

Comment: I am not aware of any issues at the moment, but I don't use htlatex myself and not having an MWE I can't really test it. And it will depend on your package versions. There have been problems in the past when `biblatex` changed internal macros that `htlatex` relied on. In the last months I haven't seen any complaints in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that some `biblatex` style doesn't work, but our test suite based on standard styles compiles correctly. We really need a `mwe` in this  case.

BTW, it is better to use `make4ht` for this kind of stuff, because you can easily control what commands should be called. Save the following code as `mybuild.mk4`:

```
Make:add("biber","biber ${input}")
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

This build file add support for `biber` command, it is called by default. If you want to make a quick compilation, you can use `-m draft` command line option for `make4ht`.

So, for full compilation call

```
make4ht -ue mybuild.mk4 filename.tex
```

and for quick compilation

```
make4ht -ue mybuild.mk4 -m draft  filename.tex
```

For the following TeX file:

```
%
% This file briefly presents the main citation commands. It also
% illustrates the typical structure of a document based on biblatex.
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
% We load the babel package and specify the main language of the
% document. If babel is detected, biblatex will automatically adjust
% to the default language of the document.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%
% We load the csquotes package, which is required for
% language-specific quotation marks. See the csquotes manual for
% further information about this package.
\usepackage{csquotes}
%
% We are using the 'authoryear' style in this example.
% The default is the 'numerical' style.
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
%
% We use the database biblatex-examples.bib.
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%
% Some generic settings.
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\section*{Standard citation commands}

\subsection*{The \cmd{cite} command}

% The \cite command prints a bare citation without parentheses.

\cite{companion}

\cite[59]{companion}

\cite[see][]{companion}

\cite[see][59--63]{companion}

\subsection*{The \cmd{parencite} command}

% The \parencite command, which is intended for in-text citations,
% encloses the citation in parentheses. Note that the 'numeric' and
% 'alphabetic' styles use square brackets instead.

This is just filler text \parencite{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[59]{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][]{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][59--63]{companion}.

\subsection*{The \cmd{footcite} command}

% The \footcite command is similar to \parencite, except that the
% citation is given in a footnote.

This is just filler text.\footcite{companion}

This is just filler text.\footcite[59]{companion}

This is just filler text.\footcite[See][]{companion}

This is just filler text.\footcite[See][59--63]{companion}

\subsection*{The \cmd{textcite} command}

% The \textcite command is intended for citations integrated in the
% flow of text, replacing the subject of the sentence.

\textcite{companion} show that this is just filler text.

\textcite[59]{companion} show that this is just filler text.

% With \textcite, the first optional argument is of limited use
% only, since you could simply place the prenote in front of the
% citation. It is still supported for the sake of consistency.

\textcite[see][]{companion} show that this is just filler text.

\textcite[see][59--63]{companion} show that this is just filler text.

\section*{Style-independent commands}

\subsection*{The \cmd{autocite} command}

% The point of the \autocite command is that it automatically adapts
% to the predominant citation format (inline or footnote) normally
% used with the selected citation style. It should be used at the
% end of the sentence and usually works like \parencite or
% \footcite, depending on the citation style and the setting of the
% 'autocite' package option. With the author-year style used in this
% example, it works like \parencite:

This is just filler text \autocite{companion}.

\section*{Text commands}

% There are a few predefined commands for bibliographic data which
% is frequently used in the flow of text. Note that biblatex also
% grants access to all lists and fields at a lower level, see below.

\citeauthor{companion} show that this is just filler text.

% Note that \citetitle will use the 'shorttitle' field, if
% available.

See the \citetitle{companion} for more filler text.

% \citetitle*, on the other hand, always prints the 'title'
% field.

See also: \citetitle*{companion}. It has more filler text.

\citetitle*{companion} by \citeauthor{companion} was
published in \citeyear{companion}.

\section*{Special commands}

% The \nocite command adds an entry to the bibliography without
% printing any citation. If the argument is an asterisk (i.e.,
% '\nocite{*}'), all entries found in the bib file are added to the
% bibliography.

No citation here.\nocite{knuth:ct}

% The \fullcite command prints a verbose citation similar to the
% full bibliography entry.

\fullcite{companion}

% \footfullcite is similar to \fullcite, except that the citation is
% put in a footnote.

This is just filler text.\footfullcite{companion}

\section*{Low-level commands}

% The commands in this section grant low-level access to all
% bibliographic data. See the biblatex manual for details about the
% different data types (name lists, literal lists, fields).

% The \citename command prints a name list. For example, the
% \citeauthor command shown above is similar to the following
% low-level command:

\citename{companion}{author}

% The \citelist command is similar to \citename but prints literal
% lists.

\citelist{companion}{publisher}

% The \citefield command prints fields. For example, the
% \citetitle* command shown above is similar to the following
% low-level command (except for the formatting):

\citefield{companion}{title}

% The list of references is printed by way of \printbibliography.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

You'll get the following result:

[image]